# Time durations matching mysql query or php code

Tags: php, mysql

My busy time duration's in a day are 08:30-12:00, 13:00-17:15. If any of my time duration is intersect at database time duration like 17:00-22:00, then do not show any mysql query result. But any of my time duration do not intersect at database time  duration like 18:00-22:00, then show mysql query result.

Or, how can I get same result in php code.

Comment: how do you store time durations? two columns?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: First column store time durations like  02:15-04:30, 08:30-12:00, 13:00-17:15 etc. Second column store one time duration like 12:30-08:00.

Comment: Can you change the way you store data? Meaning, can you store the start and end of a period as two TIME columns instead of a VARCHAR?

If you can't do that, you'll need to do some parsing in the query, which will result in a query more complex than it needs to be.

Comment: Mr. Richard St-Cyr , if  I change the way to store data like your suggestion then what is the way to solve the problem.